# не выводит русский в консоль windows

Tags: php, python, cmd, bat

В один момент сломался вывод русского теста в консоль.
И внутри IDE (встроенных терминалах) и в cmd консоли
я так и не понял что произошло. Везде стали вместо

```
тест привет
```

выходить

```
ЄхёЄ яЁштхЄ
```

что случилось не понятно. Пробовал в коде питона указывать разную кодировку. в начале файла и utf8 и 1251 не помогает. и ладно бы в питоне, но сломалось сразу везде, и phpstorm криво выводит и cmd запуска скрипта, такая же беда....

Comment: посему напрашивается мысль, может дело в настройках терминала?

Comment: в виндовских терминалах был прикол раньше, не знаю как сейчас, но там надо было в настройках выбрать что-то, но главное НЕ "точечные шрифты" (так и называются). ну и сверить кодировки, в которой сохоаняетч файл

Comment: `chcp 65001`  какой нить тоже не спасает?

Comment: Ешкин кот, помогло: chcp 1251  и норм русские символы пошли без применения decode... а как она так сломалась то. методом тыка понял, что у меня стояла chcp 866

Comment: Консоль в windows использует двухбайтовый юникод - вот его и используйте.